# How the Logic app will trigger, if we insert the multiple records into Dynamic 365

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I have developed one Logic App Workflow to insert the records into azure SQL database whenever user creating the record in Dynamic 365. But I have doubt like if 1000 records created in Dynamics 365 at a time then how the logic app will trigger, either like 1000 times sequentially executed or parallel.

Answer (score 1):

Logic App runs are always executed in parallel (i.e. if you are using a batch trigger, and it fetches k records, then all k runs will be executed in parallel). This is documented here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-loops-and-scopes#spliton-and-debatching

If this is not the desired behaviour, then you can set the 'singleton' operation option on your trigger (it does not work for batch triggers yet though) Here is a good writeup: https://blog.jeroenmaes.eu/2016/11/creating-a-logic-apps-singleton-instance/.